# batch file for getting individual path of subfolder file

Tags: batch-file, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, folderbrowserdialog

I have a parent folder.
In that i have few more sub-folder.
In this sub folder i have my desired files(.jpg files)
Ex: Parent folder : Test
Sub-folder : Folder1, Folder2, Folder 3
Inside each of the subfolder I have files as 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg
I have written a batch file getting this images paths as

```
for i in D:\Test\*\*.jpg; do convert -strip -interlace Plane -quality 80 $i $i; done
```

it didnt work for me.
will the $i gives me path some thing like D:\Test\Folder1\1.jpg ..?

Comment: Have a look here and see how FOR works in Windows BATCH files because at the moment your script is really a Unix `bash` script... http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html

Answer (score 0):

In batch you access your variables with `%i%`. In FOR constructs, you have to use `%%i`. `$i` ist bash, not batch.